# Compute hash code of a string for bucketing with uniform distribution

Tags: .net, hash, bucket

I have a large dataset that won't fit into a single Cassandra DB partition. I'd like to place the data into different buckets with uniform distribution.  I was planning to use .NET's GetHashCode() method, but it does not guarantee compatibility across .NET versions.  Is there are any hashing/bucketing algorithms that I can use to uniformly distribute data in a partition?

Comment: Have you already read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21115750/90475

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Comment: This is an odd question - Cassandra is going to has your partition key using murmur3 or md5 anyway. Why can't you just use some meaningful part of the data as the partition key so that you're able to query it later?